# Pandas resample, groupby, size leads to inconsistent outputs

Tags: pandas, group-by, pandas-resample

I have 2 dataframes [df1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QZ1C.png) and [df2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmqh4.png), that are identical in structure:

I ran the following command on each of the dataframes:

```
df_grouped = df1.set_index("timestamp") # with df2 as well
df_grouped = df_grouped.groupby("doc_sentiment").resample(bin_res).size()
df_grouped = pd.DataFrame(df_grouped)
df_grouped.head()
```

And the output I received was inconsistent between the dfs. For [df1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g73Ew.png) one the output had the timestamps as the index. This is the expected output.

However, for [df2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGi4O.png), the output had the timestamps as the columns.

Comment: Please add your dataframes in reproducible form (not as images).